# InputFilter for two capital letters and one or two digits, works only if the first input is a digit

Tags: java, android, android-textinputedittext, input-filtering, android-input-filter

I need to restrict the input that can be entered into a `TextInputEditText` to two capital letters and one or two digits, as in AB01, CS8, XY99 or ND5.

So I wrote this method:

```
/**
 * @return an InputFilter that restricts input to the format of two capital letters and one or two digits
 */
public static InputFilter getClientIdInputFilter() {
    return (source, start, end, dest, dstart, dend) -> {
        Log.v(DEBUG_TAG, "----\nsource: " + source + ", start: " + start + ", end: " + end + ", dest: " + dest + ", dstart: " + dstart + ", dend: " + dend);
        String destTxt = dest.toString();
        String input = destTxt.substring(0, dstart) + source.subSequence(start, end) + destTxt.substring(dend);
        Log.v(DEBUG_TAG, input);
        if (input.matches("^[A-Z]{0,2}[0-9]{0,2}$")) {
            if (input.length() == 1 && input.matches("^[0-9]$")) {
                Log.v(DEBUG_TAG, "Invalid input A");
                return "";
            }
            if (input.length() == 2 && !input.matches("^[A-Z]{2}$")) {
                Log.v(DEBUG_TAG, "Invalid input B");
                return "";
            }
            Log.v(DEBUG_TAG, "Valid input");
            return null;
        }
        Log.v(DEBUG_TAG, "Invalid input C");
        return "";
    };
}
```

That I use like this:

```
TextInputEditText clientId = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.edit_text_client_id);
InputFilter[] clientIdFilters = new InputFilter[1];
clientIdFilters[0] = InputFilterUtils.getClientIdInputFilter();
clientId.setFilters(clientIdFilters);
```

It *almost* works perfectly...

The problem is that **only** when starting typing from an empty `textfield`, after the first two capital letters (so at the 3rd one) the field gets deleted completely. If, instead, a number is entered first (and gets correctly ignored), if you continue to type letters, when reaching the 3rd letter, this time the first two remains and the user can continue entering the digits...

I don't have a clue for this behavior (I added some logging entries, but it's not clear anyway)

Comment: @Zain why did you delete your answer?

Comment: Hey dentex; I just thought I couldn't enhance it anymore; and I wasn't able to reproduce the new behavior you encountered; hopefully you'd find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using regex for this? This is a simple validation logic.

```
public static InputFilter getClientIdInputFilter() {
    return (source, start, end, dest, dstart, dend) -> {
        Log.v(DEBUG_TAG, "----\nsource: " + source + ", start: " + start + ", end: " + end + ", dest: " + dest + ", dstart: " + dstart + ", dend: " + dend);
        String destTxt = dest.toString();
        String input = destTxt.substring(0, dstart) + source.subSequence(start, end) + destTxt.substring(dend);
        Log.v(DEBUG_TAG, input);
        
        // changes start from here
        if (input.length() != 3 && input.length() != 4)
            return "";
        int numberOfCapitalLetters = 0, nuberOfDigits = 0;
        for (char i: input.toCharArray()) { // loop over all the letters
            if (i >= 'A' && i <= 'Z') // capital letter
                numberOfCapitalLetters += 1;
            else if (i >= '0' && i <= '9')
                nuberOfDigits += 1;
            else 
                return ""; // only capital letters and numbers allowed
        }
        if ((numberOfCapitalLetters == 2) && ((nuberOfDigits == 1) || (nuberOfDigits == 2)))
            return null; // valid
        else
            return "";
    };
}
```

Comment: I checked the answer: the problem is that now the text shows up ONLY when is at least, i.e., "AB1", not earlier. So, while typing, you don't see anything, until the whole matching text pops up.

Answer (score 0):

As I can understand @xenon134's answer, it doesn't actually check if the first and the second characters are letters, so, since the the input should be limited to 3 or 4 characters, I would go to a more hardcoded solution and not overengineer it, so:

```
public static InputFilter getClientIdInputFilter() {
    return (source, start, end, dest, dstart, dend) -> {
        Log.v(DEBUG_TAG, "----\nsource: " + source + ", start: " + start + ", end: " + end + ", dest: " + dest + ", dstart: " + dstart + ", dend: " + dend);
        String destTxt = dest.toString();
        String input = destTxt.substring(0, dstart) + source.subSequence(start, end) + destTxt.substring(dend);
        Log.v(DEBUG_TAG, input);
        
        // changes start from here
        if (input.length() == 1 && (input.charAt(0) < 'A' || input.charAt(0) > 'Z'))
            return ""
        if (input.length() == 2 && (input.charAt(1) < 'A' || input.charAt(1) > 'Z'))
            return ""
        if(input.length() == 3 && (input.charAt(2) < '0' || input.charAt(2) > '9')) 
            return "";
        if(input.length() == 4) {
            char ch4 = input.charAt(3);
            if(ch4 < '0' || ch4 > '9') 
                return "";
        }
        if (input.length() > 4)
            return "";
        
        return null; //valid
    };
}
```

*pardon me if I have forgotten any semicolon as I'm working with Kotlin for a while now, also not sure if I can get the char by index like that in Java, you might need to use `input.charAt(index)`

*Additionally, you can extract some code to check whether a char is a letter or a number on separate functions so the code looks more readable*:

- `public static boolean isLetter(char c) { ... }`
- `public static boolean isNumber(char c) { ... }`

Comment: yes, `input.charAt(index)` is needed. Anyway, I checked the answer: the problem is that now the text shows up ONLY when is at least, i.e., "AB1", not earlier. So, while typing, you don't see anything, until the whole matching text pops up.

Comment: For that, I need to see the previous code where this validation method is being used, the validation itself seems to work, no?

Comment: Please check the test project: https://www.dropbox.com/s/jfql3hzxdecx1mx/TestApplication.zip?dl=0
It was really as simple as I said in the question.

Comment: Did you take a look at the test project eventually? Thanks @ndriqa

Comment: @dentex yeah i checked it, it should now work. I have updated the answers.

Comment: basically, earlier i was filtering out if the text was not valid, without checking if the text was finished or not, now i check each case to be sure

Comment: it looks good actually... but unfortunately it works exactly the same as the code in my answer...

Answer (score 0):

If you want use regex method use below.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[A-Z]{2}\\d{1,2}");
    
String input = dest.subSequence(0, dstart)
             + source.toString()
             + dest.subSequence(dend, dest.length());

Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
if (!matcher.matches()) {
    return "";
}

return null;
```

Comment: I checked the answer: the problem is that now the text shows up ONLY when is at least, i.e., "AB1", not earlier. So, while typing, you don't see anything, until the whole matching text pops up. In addition, it doesn't prevent further input, permitting to typing, i.e. "AAAAAA"